# On $\sigma$-algebra generated by sets

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Given $\mathcal{S}$ a collection of subsets of $X$ and $A\subset X$. To show that $\sigma(\mathcal{S}\cap A)=\sigma(S)\cap A$, where for any collection of $\mathcal C$ of subsets of $X$, $\mathcal C\cap A=\{C\cap A:C\in \mathcal C\}$.

Since, $\mathcal S\cap A\subset \sigma(\mathcal S)\cap A$, therefore, $\sigma(\mathcal S\cap A)\subset \sigma(\mathcal S)\cap A$. But how to show the reverse inclusion? Any hint will be beneficial for me.

Comment: You need to show that $\sigma(\mathcal{S})\cap A$ is a σ-algebra, even for the direction you did. For the other direction, consider the set of $C\subseteq X$ for which $C\cap A\in\sigma(\mathcal{S})$.